# «Поднимаем в честь» или просто — «в честь»?

Tags: фразеология

Как будет правильно? «Поднимаем в честь тебя тост»? «В честь тебя тост»?

Answer (score 3):

Я думаю, в прямом значении - сказать тост или поднять бокалы. Поднять тост - получается метонимическое значение. Насколько оно нормативно? Не знаю. Мне не нравится. НО в  словаре Шведовой употребление тост со значением  *бокал вина* отмечено как вполне допустимое.  А у Ожегова "тост"  только одно значение имеет - речь.

Answer (score 0):

Я всегда знал одно словосочетание с словом "тост" - " предложить тост за кого-то или за что-то"